# Can't create Configure Product

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product

When i create configure product and selected attribute.
I stuck on this page [image]

Comment: check the browser console to identify if there is any error showing or not. There might be chance because of error it is not loading the requested content.

Comment: Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom loader_old.js:213:21


ReferenceError: canCreateOption is not defined[Learn More] knockout.js line 2624 > Function:3:109